# synchronising local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, local-storage

In the good old days Javascript was singlethreaded. It was relatively straightforwards to avoid the horrors of thread coordination

Unfortunately now I am in the position where I need to share information across several tabs using the local storage. My understanding is that chrome runs each tab in a different thread. This information needs to be updated on a timer. I want to make sure that the date isn't updated by each tab, but only once every time period, as the cost of updating is high (on the backend)

My approach is to have a variable in the shared local storage called 'nextUpdateTime', and have a thread in each tab that regularly polls this. If the time is more than the next update time they can call the update method (and update the nextUpdateTime). On a classical javascript execution engine this would just work, but now I have the problem of Chrome and WorkerTheads.

Ideally I would have an operating supported mutex that would allow me to construct some sort of atomic operation. I have no idea how to do this in Javascript. LocalStorage is thread safe (thank goodness) but there is no way that I can find to do atomic operations on it.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for how to approach this?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you've always had the issue of race-conditions among multiple tabs, because as you've pointed out, each tab is its own separate thread. I also don't see what Web Workers have to do with this problem, but as far as the solution, why can't you manage this expensive backend operation by keeping track of a client session and updating once per session rather than once per tab (or what I assume to be is an open connection or something)?

Comment: The race conditions would kill me personally. [Maybe use a service worker?](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I suspect the answer is simple: I don't know how to do something once every ten minutes once per session. I can set a timeout each time a page is loaded, but that will be executed once per thread. Because it's once per thread I have to coordinate between the threads. Once we have shared mutable state, we are in a mess and I'm wondering what solutions people have for that. I don't know if there is a way to do something only 'once per session' instead of one per state: any ideas?

Comment: Thank you Oskar. I'll start looking into them and see if they help

Comment: And... service workers look perfect except for browser compatibility issues. They are too new and for example aren't in IE (a requirement for the application in question)